# Завершается Android приложение из-за нехватки ресурсов?

Tags: android

Создал простенький аудиоплеер для Android в Android Studio, которое воспроизводит mp3 файлы с удаленного сервера.

Приложение может работать в фоновом режиме.

Мое `Activity` также запускает `Service`, который отображается в Notifications как `layout` с кнопкой Play/Stop.

Все работает в фоне без проблем, пока я не начинаю активно пользоваться другими приложениями (открываю сразу несколько новых приложений, загружаю в них данные и т.п.).

В результате через какое-тов время мое приложение завершается, причем событие `OnDestory` у `Activity` не вызывается.

Размер ОЗУ в моем устройстве - 1Г.
Подозреваю, что система убивает мое приложение из-за нехватки ресурсов.

**Вопрос:** если проблема именно в этом, то как ее решить? Как запретить системе убивать мое приложение, когда не хватает ресурсов?

Comment: воспроизведение происходит в сервисе, или в Activity?

Comment: Посмотри onDestroy вашего сервиса, а не активити. можно оживлять сервис именно в этом методе

Comment: По клику в Activity создается сервис, в котором начинается воспроизведение.

Comment: Тогда скажите, вы вызываете в сервисе `startForeground`?

Comment: Нет, `startForeground` я не использую. Спасибо за помощь! Буду пробовать